# Toyota corolla 2006 wont start

Tags: toyota, starting, corolla

I bought a new battery and my car still won't start it has dash lights but when I turn the key the lights go out and nothing happens

Comment: With the dash light on, do things like the wipers, headlights heater fan work?

Comment: Are both battery cables free of corrosion, powdery residue from battery acid venting? Main grounds; battery to chassis, chassis to engine block,  free of corrosion?